# Apache+WSGI Django Docker - Возникает ошибка при запуске Django: RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant

Tags: django, docker, apache2, wsgi, mod-wsgi

Есть такая связка Apache+WSGI Django Docker. При запуске контейнера дефолтная страница Апач открывается нормально. Но при переходе на какие-нибудь страницы с приложением ДЖанго не открывается, а в логах ошибка:
Это лог в контейнере

```
root@828dcbc18f43:/# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
mod_wsgi (pid=9): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=9): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/home/test/app1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/home/test/app1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/home/test/app1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
 RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

А это конфиг файл апача для приложения Django:

```
        WSGIPythonHome /home/test/app1/venv
        WSGIPythonPath /home/test/app1/backend


<VirtualHost *:80/api/user>
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/test/app1/backend/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/wsgi.py
#        WSGIPythonHome /home/test/app1/venv
#        WSGIPythonPath /home/test/app1/backend

        <Directory /home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/>

                ## NEW
                Require all granted

                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
#                Order allow,deny
#                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.key

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/test/app1/backend/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/wsgi.py
#        WSGIPythonHome /home/test/app1/venv
#        WSGIPythonPath /home/test/app1/backend

        <Directory /home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
#                Order allow,deny
#                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Возможно я не верно подключил виртуальную Среду для Джанго. Я уже многое перепробовал - ничего не помогло. В чём может быть проблема?
P.S. - Вне  контейнера всё работает с этими конфигами без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После более внимательного изучения логов нашёл вот такие записи:

```
    mod_wsgi (pid=10): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=10): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/test/app1/backend/otu_it/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/test/app1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
     import psycopg as Database
   File "/home/test/app1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
     from . import pq  # noqa: F401 import early to stabilize side effects
   File "/home/test/app1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg/pq/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
     import_from_libpq()
   File "/home/test/app1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg/pq/__init__.py", line 106, in import_from_libpq
     raise ImportError(
 ImportError: no pq wrapper available.
 Attempts made:
 - couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
 - couldn't import psycopg 'binary' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_binary'
 - couldn't import psycopg 'python' implementation: libpq library not found
```

Далее я установил дополнительные модули

```
pip install psycopg2

pip install psycopg2-binary
```

И всё заработало.